# Cannot read default.graphdb neo4j database in JAVA application

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm using MAC OS and trying to read the graph.db file using below script in my JAVA application

```
GraphDatabaseFactory graphDbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = graphDbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("/Users/Neo4j/default.graphdb"));
```

But I'm receiving following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /Users/Neo4j/default.graphdb
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:205)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:120)
  at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:133)
  at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:126)
  at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:101)
  at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:193)
  at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:70)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58520', transport: 'socket'
  at org.caleydo.neo4j.plugins.kshortestpaths.RunAlgo.main(RunAlgo.java:16)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@6c7ff68a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:443)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:201)
  ... 7 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No dependency satisfies type class org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:71)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:67)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:395)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
  ... 12 more
```

Comment: have you followed the examples shared by neo4j on [github](https://github.com/neo4j-examples).  they may be helpful to get the application fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265771/neo4j-no-dependency-satisfies-type-class-org-neo4j-kernel-api-index-schemaindex