# Neo4j embedded in spring using maven

Tags: spring, maven, neo4j

I try to create a spring boot project with neo4j embedded.
My project is at its beginning: there no NodeEntities nor repositories yet.

It just contains the SpringBootApplication class, a dummy rest controller, and a Neo4jConfiguration file.

My problem: the app does not start. I get:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [eu/alkismavridis/mathasm/db/Neo4jConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ConnectionException: Error connecting to embedded graph
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at eu.alkismavridis.mathasm.MathasmApplication.main(MathasmApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ConnectionException: Error connecting to embedded graph
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ConnectionException: Error connecting to embedded graph
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver.configure(EmbeddedDriver.java:94) ~[neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:82) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at eu.alkismavridis.mathasm.db.Neo4jConfiguration.getSessionFactory(Neo4jConfiguration.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.alkismavridis.mathasm.db.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cba62fa3.CGLIB$getSessionFactory$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.alkismavridis.mathasm.db.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cba62fa3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d6eed0e3.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at eu.alkismavridis.mathasm.db.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cba62fa3.getSessionFactory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /home/alkis/data
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:125) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:137) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:130) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:107) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:199) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:75) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver.setGraphDatabase(EmbeddedDriver.java:104) ~[neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver.configure(EmbeddedDriver.java:91) ~[neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@191a0351' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "No dependency satisfies type class org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.IndexProvider".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466) ~[neo4j-common-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107) ~[neo4j-common-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445) ~[neo4j-common-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107) ~[neo4j-common-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No dependency satisfies type class org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.IndexProvider
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:73) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:68) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:387) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8,fd05a33c832a50786889cc2ea5714baa31795459]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445) ~[neo4j-common-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265771/neo4j-no-dependency-satisfies-type-class-org-neo4j-kernel-api-index-schemaindex), but is was configured with gradle, not maven, so I cannot really apply its solution.

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eu.alkismavridis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mathasm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mathasm</name>
    <description>Some app</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.8</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.data.neo4j.embedded.enabled=true
```

And my Neo4j configuration class:

```
package eu.alkismavridis.mathasm.db;


import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager;

import org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.IndexProvider;

@Configuration
//@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "eu.alkismavridis.mathasm")
@EntityScan("eu.alkismavridis.mathasm.core")
public class Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {
        //org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder().build();



        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder()
                .uri("file:///home/alkis/data")
                .build();




        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(),
                "com.baeldung.spring.data.neo4j.domain");
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
    }
}
```

I haven't tried a lot since I cannot really understand the nature of the problem... Until now I have tried to return different configurations from getConfiguration(), but without succes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to resolve my issue by following the steps of this git repo:
https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j

Step 1. I included

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId 
    <version>3.2.9</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

in my pom.xml,

step 2. I renamed  Neo4jConfiguration.getSessionFactory to Neo4jConfiguration.sessionFactory

Setp 3. I changed the string "com.baeldung.spring.data.neo4j.domain" to my actual package that my entities lie solved my problem. The app now runs.